# Multicomparison Test of Independent Events

Tags: probability, p-value, combinatorics

I can explain more if needed, but simply I have a strand of DNA and I want know some aggregate probability of the observed phenomenon being due to chance.

As an example I have something like this:

```
TCGA
```

Each position can get changed to one of the three other available letters and the probability with which that happens is known. Something like:

```
80% of G's change to A's
10% of G's change to C's
10% of G's change to T's
```

I have repeat observations and have calculated probability of the observations happening by chance for each site. So if the G changed to an A in all of three observations, I calculated the probability of this event by:

```
0.8^3 = 0.512
```

I have these probabilities calculated for each letter in the strand, so something like this:

```
0.3,0.7,0.5,0.1
```

Now that I have probabilities for each letter how can I calculate an overall probability of observing all the changes together? The null hypothesis being that the changes seen across all letters in the DNA is due to random chance alone.

Comment: When you say "due to random chance alone" do you mean specifically that the events across different letters are independent?

Comment: Well they are independent biologically. So what I am thinking is that with the known probabilities with which the letters change, what is the probability that with X events at each location we see the changes that we see by chance.

Comment: I changed the tag to combinatorics which I think fits better here, but feel free to revert it if you prefer.